# The Apple TV 2 has 110V/220V PSU or just 110V?

Tags: appletv

I'm going to the USA, and I am planning to buy an Apple TV there for use it in Europe.

Why I should do that?

Because the $99 Apple TV is sold in Europe for €120 ($170). Why pay almost the double for the same stuff?

OK, so the core question: is the internal Apple TV 2 PSU 110V/220V, or just 110V for units sold in the USA?

Comment: I'm almost sure it will be fine. You will need to find another power cord though, but it's a standard 8-shaped connector. However I can't speak from experience.

Comment: I have tons of the us plug adapters :) On dealextreme are sold for just $0.8 + free shipping

Comment: A plug would serve you well, but that type of cable is also very cheap and easy to get by, if you are interested in reducing the clutter to a minimum.

Comment: Why travel to the US?  Won't Amazon ship it to you?  They just dropped the price: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001FA1NK0?ie=UTF8&tag=jimtut-20&linkCode=ur2&camp=1789&creative=9325

Comment: Amazon wont ship to my place. "Shipping: Currently, item can be shipped only within the U.S." Anyway, I am traveling to the US for another reason than buying an Apple TV ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [US Apple Store webpage](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_ipod/family/apple_tv) says that the current Apple TV (2) has:

> Power: Built-in 6-watt universal power supply

So yes, it looks like it will be fine in Europe.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, according to [Apple TV on Apple Online Store description page](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_ipod/family/apple_tv), the power is a Built-in 6-watt universal power supply.

But another important thing needs to check is to see if the power plug matches the socket in your country.

Comment: The Apple TV 2 comes with a C7 coupler. For example I bought my ATV in the US, but am using it in Germany, I just replaced the cable with a german C7 cable.

Answer (score 2):

I bought it and I confirm that the US version works fine with european 220V/50hz (fine print on the box says also 110V/220V compatibility)

Comment: What part of box does it say that? I read th ewhole box in and out a several times, there is nothing says about 110v/220v.Thanx

Comment: Maybe they changed the design from ATV2 to ATV3

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works 100%. I used an old figure 8 cable, ran it straight from 220V 50Hz socket and the Apple TV worked great.